# Alternative to the word "notice board/collage" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I visited a local restaurant recently. They had a board on the wall, which had a collection newspaper articles(about local sport teams) pinned to it.

In my native country, we have the word **notice board(at office/at your dorm etc)**, where all the important memo are pinned, for everyone to see.

The boards that I saw, was like a notice board/collage(in my home country).

Can somebody suggest an alternative world to **collage/notice board**?

Comment: I would call it a notice board. A collage is an artwork made by sticking small pictures and other things to a background (it means 'glueing' in French).

Answer (score 1):

As @KateBunting has mentioned, the word "collage" is mostly used in the art context.

You have already come up with the right answer which is "**noticeboard**", but if you are looking for something else, here are some alternatives: ;-)

**bulletin board**, **pin board**

Personally I think **pin board** has just the right feel to it.

[See this Wikipedia page for more information.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board)